# C++ How does a relation of pointers and class members work?

Tags: c++, pointers

in the example below I've made a very simple class and there are a couple of things which I don't understand.

```
class Keylogger {
public:
    void Hook();
    void Unhook();

private:
    HHOOK hHook;
    LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

void Keylogger::Hook() {

    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, this->LowLevelKeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
}

void Keylogger::Unhook() {
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
}
```

If I understand correctly, all members of a class are local (in stack) when the class object is defined and destroyed once operations ends. (function exits).

In the example above, I'm trying to assign HHOOK to a private member hHook, thus receiving an error: **"non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"**

Why can't a variable just be assigned that way and what does the error exactly mean?

In which case should pointers be created to members and how exactly should those be used with **this->**? Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see anything wrong with the code above. I also don't see anything having to do with `pointer to member` variables.

Comment: Hi, I referred this question as pointer to member due to the error that I'm receiving. Yeah, I don't really understand what could be wrong either.

Comment: The problem is with supplying the member function as a HOOKPROC parameter -- you have to give a static member or global function here.

Comment: The objects you create aren't always on the stack. If you dynamically allocate them, then they are on the heap. If you dynamically allocated them, then they stay in memory until you de-allocate them. Otherwise, if it's on the stack, the variables will de-construct when they go out of the scope.

Comment: _"all members of a class are local (in stack)"_ That depends on how the class is instantiated, which is why terms like "in stack" should not be horribly misused the way they typically are.

Comment: Thank you guys, I understand now, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this call:

```
 hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, this->LowLevelKeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
```

you are trying to pass a member function : `this->LowLevelKeyboardProc` as if this was a free function (non-member). This will not work, member functions are not like free functions. You can call them only using class instance pointer and pointer to member function.

This API function `SetWindowsHookEx` requires free function, so you should either make LowLevelKeyboardProc static, or move it outside the class.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now :)

Comment: Why does making it static allow it to act as a free function, without moving it outside of the class?

Comment: Because you don't need an instance of class to call its static member function.